# How to get the latest date from joined table

Tags: mysql, join

I want my table `message_mapping` ordered by the latest date available for a  `message_id` in table `messages` (`message_id` is available in both tables).

If I try to use `MAX(messages.send_at)` in the `ORDER BY` statement, it does not change the result

```
SELECT * FROM message_mapping 
LEFT JOIN messages ON message_mapping.message_id = messages.message_id
WHERE landlord = 16 OR tenant = 16
GROUP BY message_mapping.message_id
ORDER BY messages.send_at DESC
```

This is how my tables look like:

message_mapping:

```
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| message_id | landlord | tenant | property_id |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 34         | 194      | 16     | 160         |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 35         | 194      | 16     | 318         |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 36         | 194      | 207    | 160         |
+------------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

messages:

```
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| id  | message_id | sender | receiver | message_text | send_at        |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 256 | 34         | 16     | 194      | lorem ipsum  | 10.05.19 22:37 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 257 | 34         | 194    | 16       | lorem ipsum  | 10.05.19 22:38 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 258 | 34         | 194    | 16       | lorem ipsum  | 20.05.19 22:38 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 259 | 34         | 194    | 16       | lorem ipsum  | 25.05.19 22:38 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 260 | 35         | 16     | 194      | lorem ipsum  | 13.05.19 22:38 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

Column send_at is formatted as DATETIME and looks like this: 2019-05-13 22:39:00
I don´t know why it is d

What I would like to see is table message_mapping (where sender or receiver = 16) ordered by the latest date from table messages.

Any idea what I could change?

Comment: @Strawberry I have adjusted my question and added hopefully all required information. Thanks

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to select the max() value fir the send_at column in the select as well. With that, the ordering worked well.

```
SELECT message_mapping.*, max(messages.send_at) AS latest_send_at
FROM message_mapping 
LEFT JOIN messages ON message_mapping.message_id = messages.message_id
WHERE landlord = ? OR tenant = ?
GROUP BY message_mapping.message_id
ORDER BY latest_send_at DESC");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use max(messages.send_at) in the select and dont use an order by i.e.

```
SELECT messages.message_id, max(messages.send_at) 
FROM message_mapping 
LEFT JOIN messages ON message_mapping.message_id 
= messages.message_id
WHERE landlord = 16 OR tenant = 16
GROUP BY message_mapping.message_id
```